# Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String error when I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase to viewpager2

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

For my application, I added a ViewPager2 to show the recommended containing image, name, and country. But when I try to retrieve data from firebase this error shows. I tried tweaking the code but I think I'm only making it worse because the error is replaced by No setter/field for a class error. I have been stuck with the same error for a few days now and still can't solve it. I badly need help.

Below is my code for MainActivity

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.child("Packages");
        recommendList = new ArrayList<Recommendation>();
        adapter = new RecommendAdapter(this, recommendList);
        recommendViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        setupRecommendViewPager();



        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            List<Recommendation> recommendList = new ArrayList<>();
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){

                    Recommendation recommendation = dataSnapshot.getValue(Recommendation.class);
                    //String recommendation = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                    recommendList.add(recommendation);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

And this is my Recommendation.class

```
public class Recommendation {

    public String package_attractions;
    public String package_availability;
    public String package_country;
    public String package_description;
    public String package_name;
    public String package_photos;
    public Double package_price;
    public Double package_rating;
    public String package_region;
    public String package_video;

    public Recommendation(){}

    public Recommendation(String package_attractions, String package_availability, String package_country, String package_description, String package_name, String package_photos, Double package_price, Double package_rating, String package_region, String package_video) {
        this.package_attractions = package_attractions;
        this.package_availability = package_availability;
        this.package_country = package_country;
        this.package_description = package_description;
        this.package_name = package_name;
        this.package_photos = package_photos;
        this.package_price = package_price;
        this.package_rating = package_rating;
        this.package_region = package_region;
        this.package_video = package_video;
    }

    
    public String getPackage_attractions() {
        return package_attractions;
    }

    public void setPackage_attractions(String package_attractions) {
        this.package_attractions = package_attractions;
    }

    public String getPackage_availability() {
        return package_availability;
    }

    public void setPackage_availability(String package_availability) {
        this.package_availability = package_availability;
    }
.........
```

And this is my firebase [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBrNE.jpg)

P.S I'm only retrieving photo, name, and country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the following error:

> Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Because you're trying to convert an object (map) that exists in your database into a string, and this is not possible in Java. Why is this happening? It's because your `package_photos` field inside the database is an object:

[image]

See, you can dig deeper to get data, which basically means that this field it's **not** a String but an object (map), since each node in the Realtime Database is composed of key-value pairs.

When you're using the following line of code:

```
Recommendation recommendation = dataSnapshot.getValue(Recommendation.class);
```

It means that you're trying to map each node under "Packages" into an object of type `Recommendation`. This means that each field in the database should have the exact same type as in your class, which isn't happening. Your `package_photos` field in the database is a map, while in the class is a string, hence the error.

To solve this, you should change the type of your `package_photos` field inside the class to be either an object or a map. Since I cannot see the content of your `package_photos` node, I can only assume that you have a key that is named "url" and a value that is represented by the actual value of the URL, "https://...".

So it most likely it looks similar to this:

```
Packages
 |
 --- BG0PH108
      |
      --- package_photos
            |
            --- url: "https://..."
```

So in this case, you need to create a class with at a minimum declaration, that looks like this:

```
public class PackagePhotos {
    public String url;
}
```

Or if you want to use encapsulation:

```
public class PackagePhotos {
    private String url;

    public PackagePhotos() {}

    public PackagePhotos(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

And inside the `Recommendation` class, the field should be changed to:

```
public class Recommendation {
    //...    
    public PackagePhotos package_photos;

    public Recommendation() {}

    //                           
    public Recommendation(..., PackagePhotos package_photos, ...) {
        //...
        this.package_photos = package_photos;
        //...
    }

    
    //...
}
```

Be aware that `package_video` filed should follow the same rules.

If you don't want to use a class, then you should simply set the type of the field to `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: I finally solved it! Thank you so much for this :)